# Which is better to call start() or run() method for thread to execute

Tags: java, multithreading

As per my understanding, when i call start() method it will call run method itself.

We can do the same thing by calling run() method . Is it ?

Like we have :

```
public class ThreadTest extends Thread{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ThreadTest t = new ThreadTest();
        t.run();
    }

}

public class ThreadTest extends Thread{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ThreadTest t = new ThreadTest();
        t.start();
    }

}
```

What is the difference between both of them?

Comment: Most of these "answers" leave out the most important part.  (@immibis came closest though.)  Thread.start() is a library method that _starts_ a thread.  The run() method is a method that _you_ write, that determines what the thread will do.  As immibis said, When your code calls run()---the method that _you_ wrote---that's no different your code calling any other method that you wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`run` is just a normal method.

If you do this:

```
class C {
    public void m() {
        while(true) {}
    }
}
C c = new C();
c.m();
System.out.println("Hello world");
```

then the infinite loop runs on the current thread, and "Hello world" never gets printed. This is *exactly the same* as:

```
class C extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        while(true) {}
    }
}
C c = new C();
c.run();
System.out.println("Hello world");
```

`start` is a "special" method which starts a new thread, and then calls `run` on the new thread.

Answer (score 1):

The first approach calls the [`run()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run()) method as a simple method call in java.

> only one (the calling thread) *main* thread is running.

But, [`t.start();`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()) creates a new `Thread` and calls its [`run()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run()) method.

> two threads (*main* and *t* runs concurrently)

Answer (score 0):

Calling `run()` directly just executes the code `synchronously` (in the same thread), just like a normal method call whereas calling `start()` executes the code `asynchronously` .

```
thread.run();
```

is `similar` to

```
thread.start();
thread.join();
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling the `run()` method directly wont help your cause. It does not spawn a new thread. Rather the `run()` method will get executed in the calling method stack (same thread).

Documentation of `Thread.start()` states that it starts a new thread and `run()` method is invoked internally.

> Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls
>   the run method of this thread.
>
> The result is that two threads are running concurrently: the current
>   thread (which returns from the call to the start method) and the other
>   thread (which executes its run method).

Answer (score 0):

If you call `start()` method on Thread object,that will create a new thread which calls `run()` method internally.
[Thread#start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start)

> Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls the run method of this thread.
>   The result is that two threads are running concurrently: the current thread (which returns from the call to the start method) and the other thread (which executes its run method).

If you call `run()` method then is normal method calling no new thread will be created.Just executes the run() method by current running thread.